# AS3 air iOS Android control volume from app

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I was wondering if someone could shed some light on how to control the volume of the device (iOS and Android) from within an air app?

I am using URLRequest to load an MP3 file which I would like to control the volume of. I have tried SoundTransform but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Via SoundTransform object to set volume value. You check this link to do 
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Working_with_Sound_12.html

Comment: Hi, this only seems to control the volume of the app. I was looking for a way to control the devices volume similar to if a user turned the volume up and down using the devices buttons.